# Is there a way to disable all SemanticLogger (Ruby) log output?

Tags: ruby, logging

I have an application that uses SemanticLogger, and creates a separate logger for each of many classes. Is there a way I can disable all SemanticLogger output, even output for those loggers that have overridden defaults?

Comment: What do you mean can you disable it? You could simply remove it from the application which would certainly disable it. Otherwise can you please explain your desired use case a bit further?

Comment: I wanted to keep the log setup and calls there, but based on a config option or command line switch, for example, optionally disable all logging. I know I could accomplish this awkwardly, e.g. by using custom appender classes that look at a flag, but was hoping there was a simpler way.

Comment: A possibly acceptable workaround would be set the global default log level to :fatal. However, any loggers that overrode the default would not get that value.